DataGrip problem with connection on Linux
I'm working on my college project from Relational Databases subject. I'm using Linux. At college we are using Oracle databases.
I'm facing problem: "the network adapter could not establish the connection". I don't know how to make this connection. Can someone help me?
Thanks :)
In "Target data source/schema" pane there's all the time  message. I don't know what to write in URL pane too.

We have a basic troubleshooting guide related to connectivity issues:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connectivity-problems.html
More details about this issue can be found in the idea log in Help - Show Log in Files
If this won't take you any further, please report this issue on our tracker
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE

First question is where is your database? Is it on a docker container? Is it an Autonomous Database in the cloud? Is it running locally?
